# Creating wildcard subdomain doesn't work

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

I want created a wildcard subdomain for each user from mysql database. The subdomain works but the page is loading without the related files (css, js).

List of user page :

```
website.com/user/index.php
```

User page :

```
website.com/user/userpage/user.php?username=john
```

This is my rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.com/user/user.php$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?).website.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*)    user.php?username=%1
```

Is there anything wrong with my rewrite code? . Thanks :D

**EDIT**

Forgot one thing this is my wildcard *.website.com directory :

```
public_html/user
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.com/user/user.php$
```

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is meant to match the hostname only, and not the path (`/user/user.php`); besides, you should escape dots (which are reserved characters in regexes), so you should change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com
```

You may be interested [in this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#ToC1) of the Apache docs.